# Reading data from file and performing matrix multiplication in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, and am trying to perform a matrix multiplication taking data from a file.  But I am unable to get the multiplication part.  Someone please help me to fix this.

While am trying to do the multiplication of 2 matrices but am unable to get the output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string line;
    int d[3][3],e[3][3],f[3][3];
    int i=0;
    int x=0;
    int j=0;
    string a[20];
    string b[20];
    string c[20];
    ifstream myfile;

    myfile.open("numeric.txt");
    while(getline (myfile,line))
    {
        if(line!=" ")
        {
            a[x]=line;
            b[x]=line;
            cout<<a[x]<<endl;
            x++;       
        }
    }
    cout<<"first Matrix"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=4;j++)
        {
            cout<<a[i][j]<<"";
        }
        cout<<endl;  
    }                              
    cout<<"Second Matrix"<<endl;
    for(i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            cout<<b[i][j]<<"";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Multiplication"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
        {
            c[i][j]=0;
            for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
            {
                c[i][j]+=a[i][k]*b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"Multiplication Result"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            cout<<c[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean there is no output, or the output is incorrect?  Are there any error messages?

Comment: Why are you using std::string for matrices? And what about `d` `e` and `f`?

Comment: You need to learn the difference between strings and numbers, but for simplicity, your program should not use `std::string` at all. Get rid of every mention of `string` and try again.

Comment: @n.m.: Well... reading a whole line and parsing in-memory *is* something we do recommend to anyone trying to `scanf()` user input, so I can see where the OP is coming from. But yes, there is some input-to-integer conversion missing here. Either directly read `myfile >>` to integer, or use [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) on the line's contents as appropriate.

Comment: @DevSolar I don't identify with "we" you speak about. I think those "we" are plain wrong. A C++ programmer that needs to input a matrix shouldn't deal with strings unless there's a specific need.

Comment: @n.m.: The "need" could be, for example, a meaningful error message including line number and line contents. And as for `scanf()` specifically the caveat against using it for potentially malformed user input is somewhat cabonical, so -- while you are of course entitled to your opinion -- I would think twice about calling others "plain wrong". Let's end it at this point, I fear we might derail it otherwise.

Comment: @DevSolar I do not recommend students voluntarily adding features like ideal error reporting to every assignment of their C++ 101 class. When there is a specific stated requirement, go ahead and implement it, you will need to know how to do that at some point in the future, but not now.

Comment: @n.m.: All I said is that reading whole lines and then taking them apart in-memory is something that *is* a valid approach (as opposed you your dealing in absolutes). Let it rest.

Comment: @DevSolar OK I agree :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example on how you write (fixed size) matrices to a file and how you can build them reading from that file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    const size_t matrixSize = 3;

    // 
    ofstream matrixOutput("matrix.txt");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++) {
            matrixOutput << j*i << ' ';
        }
        matrixOutput << '\n';
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++) {
            matrixOutput << j*i * 2 << ' ';
        }
        matrixOutput << '\n';
    }

    matrixOutput.close();

    //

    ifstream matrixData("matrix.txt");

    size_t matrixInput[matrixSize][matrixSize];
    size_t matrixInput2[matrixSize][matrixSize];

    size_t position = 0;
    size_t number = 0;

    while (matrixData >> number) {

        const size_t matrixNumber = size_t(floor(position / (matrixSize*matrixSize)));
        const size_t row = size_t(floor(position / matrixSize)) % matrixSize;

        switch (matrixNumber) {
            case 0:
                matrixInput[row][position % 3] = number; break;
            case 1: 
                matrixInput2[row][position % 3] = number; break;
        }
        position++;
    }

    matrixData.close();

    cout << "Matrices: " << endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++) {
            cout << matrixInput[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++) {
            cout << matrixInput2[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Matrices multiplication: " << endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++) {
            cout << matrixInput[i][j] * matrixInput2[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    // ...
}
```

**Note:** if you want you can write the matrix size to the file too, so you can retrieve it later and build custom size matrices.